# How to interpret this formula for the Hilbert symbol?

Tags: number-theory, p-adic-number-theory

I have a formula for the special case $p=2$ for the Hilbert symbol:

\begin{equation*}
\left( \frac{u 2^n , v 2^m}{2} \right) = (-1)^{\frac{u-1}{2}\cdot\frac{v-1}{2}}(-1)^{n\frac{v^2-1}{8}}(-1)^{m\frac{u^2-1}{8}}
\end{equation*}
with $u 2^n, v 2^m \in \mathbb{Q}_2^\times$ and $u, v\in\mathbb{Z}^\times_2$.

Simple question: How shall I interpret $\frac{u-1}{2}$, $\frac{u^2-1}{8}$, ...? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a *real* definition in the meanwhile:

Both expression have to be interpreted modulo 2. We note that the case $u, v \equiv 0 \bmod{2}$ is not possible since $u, v \in \mathbb{Z}_p^\times$, so we get (by an abuse of notation)
\begin{equation*}
 \frac{u-1}{2} := \begin{cases}0 & \text{ if }u\equiv +1 \bmod{4} \\ 1 & \text{ if }u\equiv -1 \bmod{4} \end{cases} \\
 \frac{u^2-1}{8} := \begin{cases}0 & \text{ if }u\equiv \pm1 \bmod{8} \\ 1 & \text{ if }u\equiv \pm5 \bmod{8} \end{cases} \, .
\end{equation*}

Comment: You might already know this but the first condition is the existence of a square root of -1 modulo p and the second one is the existence of a square root of 2 modulo p, ie. $u-1/2 = 1$ is equivalent to square root of -1